# Mercurial Branches vs. Compilation Flags: One Codebase -- Multiple Products

Tags: mercurial, compiler-flags

Say I'm creating a set of products that share much of their code but not all of it (For example: an application with multiple front ends: command line, Windows/MAC/Linux GUI, mobile (minimal) GUI, web GUI etc.)

Furthermore, lets say that the shared code cannot be easily split off and 'librarified'.

Im considering using mercurial named branches for the different products (e.g. branches: CLI,Windows,MAC,Linux,Mobile,Web) or compilation flags in code (e.g. `#if (FRONT_END == CLI) #elif (FRONT_END == WEB) ...`).

im not satisfied with either approaches. here are my grievances:

named branches:

- if i change a piece of shared code, i need to merge it with all branches.
  is there an hg command to do this (semi-)automatically?
- it is not easy/quick to see how a particular feature implemented across all branches (visualize the differences in one area of the code)

compilation flags:

- code clutter
- no implicit branch revision history. must do so manually (commit with a message indicating which products are affected)

can you suggest:

- ways to mitigate my qualms?
- a different point of view
- elegant ways to combine the 2 approaches

thanx

Comment: Do you build your different front ends from the same projects? And why would this have impact on the shared code? ie. why does the shared code need to know it needs to be used in a web application vs. a desktop application?

Comment: What's the problem with splitting off the shared code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, *I have* best strategy for you.

Preface: I **fiercely, furiously hate** ifdef'ed spaghetti-code

---

Named branches aren't bad, but had management's drawbacks, yes.  After some attempts and fails I stopped on "Single codebase + Multiply MQ patches" idea. With fresh Mercurial you can have even more than one queue, you can use guarded patches... as result you have one vanilla code - many (any) targets

Future reading: "Mercurial: The Definitive Guide", [Chapter 12. Managing change with Mercurial Queues](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) and [Chapter 13. Advanced uses of Mercurial Queues](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/advanced-uses-of-mercurial-queues.html)